# static_cast : Conversion function templates - are they really working?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, c++17

As far as I read [static_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) the following code should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class ConvSample
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    constexpr operator T(){
        return {};
    }
};

int main()
{
    ConvSample aInst;

    int i = aInst;
    std::cout << i << "\n";

    std::string str = static_cast<std::string>(aInst);
    std::cout << str << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

And it works perfectly with some compilers like Clang. But e.g. with MSVC or ICC not.

See [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ZxEn0N)

In general they complain about some ambiguity caused by not really working constructors provided by std::string.

In addition if I turn on Wconversion on gcc I get a segmentation fault?!

Is there something wrong in the code? Are these errors just compiler bugs?
If I change the code to not use templates it workes very well:
[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ytPiAk)

Comment: fyi all compile with `static_cast<const basic_string&>` which is an exact match for constructor (7):  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: @RichardCritten: But that would involve undefined behavior in using the reference to the temporary in the conversion function.

Comment: In the case you mentioned, it is implicitlty converted to std::string. After this implicit conversion there is a call to the copy constructor...
But that is cleary not what I want. It should just call the conversion operator (it works without static_cast or c-style cast).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard is unfortunately vague here ([expr.static.cast]/4, citations omitted):

> An expression `e` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` if there is an implicit conversion sequence from `e` to `T`, or if overload resolution for a direct-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` from `e` would find at least one viable function.  […] [T]he result object is direct-initialized from `e`. […]

Both of the enabling conditions hold here: there is an implicit conversion sequence (consisting of the desired conversion function call), and there are several viable functions for direct-initialization (because there are also implicit conversion sequences for the various single parameters for `std::string` constructors).

However, it is only the copy-initialization of the implicit conversion sequence, which refuses to convert `ConvSample` to (say) `const char*` and then to `std::string`, that provides an **unambiguous** means of producing a `std::string`: it specifically looks for conversion functions to the target type, and while it *allows* conversions to (say) `const std::string&`, common implementations do not interpret that to mean that the conversion function template should be instantiated for that type as well and become ambiguous.

The direct-initialization that is ultimately called for is ambiguous among `std::string`’s 5 single-argument constructors (6 for `std::string_view`-like types): `ConvSample` can of course be converted to the parameter type for any of them at the same “cost”.

The compilers that accept this are applying copy-initialization rules (but still allowing `explicit` conversions).  Those that reject it are applying direct-initialization, which I believe is what the wording currently requires.  The reference to implicit conversion sequences was introduced only in C++17 for [CWG242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#242), and apparently implementation divergence persists in this area.

Comment: I don't think this issue with interpretation of `static_cast` explains the implementation divergence. The exact same results are obtained with a direct initialization, `std::string str(aInst);`. Are GCC and Clang wrongly applying copy-initialization rules to direct-initialization? Perhaps, but it's unusual that I see them both have the same bug.

Comment: @Brian: That’s a good point; it does make sense that “true” direct-initialization would behave the same way, since that’s what `static_cast` is supposed to do l.  Playing with various combinations of `explicit` and parameter types, I have managed to find a GCC/Clang distinction as well; if I refine the theory I’ll definitely edit here.

Comment: @Brian: This is [CWG2327](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2327), which also concerns new C++17 wording.